Why gradle build on github trying to locate merged PR [ "couldn't find remote ref" error ]?
There was a PR which was merged into master, and the build fails with "couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/2/merge".
Just in case, the info below has any relevance to the problem at hand:
the PR was created in a forked branch from develop and develop has not been updated back from master.
Any help would be appreciated.
gradle.yml :
name: Java CI

on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
  pull_request: 
    branches: 
      - master
      - develop         


jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.2
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v4.2.1
      with:
        java-version: 11
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew build --info

Log:

    Run actions/checkout@v1
    Syncing repository: XYZ
    git version
    git version 2.43.2
    git lfs version
    git-lfs/3.5.1 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.21.8)
    git init "/home/runner/work/XYZ/XYZ"
    hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
    hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
    hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
    hint: 
    hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
    hint: 
    hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
    hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
    hint: 
    hint:   git branch -m <name>
    Initialized empty Git repository in /home/runner/work/XYZ/XYZ/.git/
    git remote add origin https://github.com/XYZ
    git config gc.auto 0
    git config --get-all http.https://github.com/XYZ.extraheader
    git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/2/merge:refs/remotes/pull/2/merge
    Error: fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/2/merge
    Warning: Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 1.611 seconds before retry.
    git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/2/merge:refs/remotes/pull/2/merge
    Error: fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/2/merge
    Warning: Git fetch failed with exit code 128, back off 6.949 seconds before retry.
    git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic ***" fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/pull/2/merge:refs/remotes/pull/2/merge
    Error: fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/pull/2/merge
    Error: Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
    Error: Exit code 1 returned from process: file name '/home/runner/runners/2.316.0/bin/Runner.PluginHost', arguments 'action "GitHub.Runner.Plugins.Repository.v1_0.CheckoutTask, Runner.Plugins"



Please include the actions/checkout step in your workflow.

Sounds like the PR/branch on the remote got deleted and just can't be fetched, can you fetch it yourself or check that it actually exists still using a git web interface or CLI?

@Azeem Thanks for your input.
It does have it though - I've just updated my original post to include the entire gradle.yml.

@shaunhusain, yes, it's still there - I can fetch it

Just wanted you to add it in the question as the logs you're showing are from that. Looks like it should b fixed if you add fetch-depth: 0.

Thank you for your suggestion, @Azeem. I created a PR based on that; waiting for the project owner to approve it. Will let you know if it'll help

@Azeem, sorry for the delay. Yes, it did fix it. Thanks so much!
